# Is it possible to have the realname from an email propagated through to outlook

Tags: windows, email, exchange-2007

we are using JIRA to manage our projects. For various reasons, it was required to move the email account from unix to an Exchange 2007 server.

We have added a mailbox for the JIRA account, since we also want to receive mails back.

In the postfix era, Outlook did not know the jira account and thus displayed the fullname from the email header. With the beautiful effect, that the name of the person posting the comment was set as the sender's name in outlook (Like: Thomas [jira]). Now, since outlook knows the sender, the email is received as "JIRA".

We are missing this piece of comfort a lot, since it allows to filter by name very easily.

Is there any way to configure Exchange to pass-through the fullname for that account only or how can we configure Exchange to accept mails from the JIRA server without requiring authentication (anonymous sending).

Thanks in advance!

Thomas

Comment: On the 2nd part (anonymous) you can setup a relay receive connector in Exchange to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is you can't. If Exchange has an SMTP address on a mailbox or a recipient, the display of that address is going to get changed to the display name of the mailbox or recipient. There is no way around it. And switching to anonymous authentication will not solve this problem because the address is not matched based on the authenticating user but the address in the header.

Comment: Thanks for making me stop searching. We will let the annoyance grow and if it is big enough, we will look for another solution (like a postfix in the middle) :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're dependent on using the display of your inbox as part of your workflow (which is kind of a hack, but hey), you can see if you can change the Jira emails to contain a custom header that is populated with the real name, and then configure Outlook to display that header.